# List comprehension with lambda function

Tags: python

```
def multipliers():
    return [lambda x: i * x for i in range(4)]


print([m(1) for m in multipliers()]) # [3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Why it's not `[0, 1, 2, 3]`? Can't understand. So, for some reason we have `i = 3` in all lambdas? Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because of Pythons [late binding closures](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/). You can fix the issue by writing:

```
def multipliers():
    return [lambda x, i=i : i * x for i in range(4)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you were trying to do?

```
def multipliers(x):
    return [i * x for i in range(4)]

print(multipliers(1)) 

>> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Why not just `print ([0, 1, 2, 3])` if we go for simplification? The OP have asked what is wrong with *their* code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why stop there? `print('[0,1,2,3]')` is easier on resources